# pagetabstrip title of viewpager dynamically from api using asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, fragment, title

### I have problem in android to get the pagetabstrip title of viewpager dynamically from webapi using asynctask and JSON. i want also return strig array from json object of array from asynctask method of doInBackground.. to on which place where i call it...which is extends to fragment.. If any one idea..please suggest me as soon as possible

page1 | page2 | page 3 | page 4
| . | .  |.  |.....

In above structure of viewpager shown that title are "Page1","Page2","Page3" which i want to dynamically from webapi using asynctask...

Answer (score 0):

store your response into anything like List

create class PagerClass that extends pagerAdapter. call constructor passes that list.

extend this method is PagerClass.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return list[position];
}
```

Comment: thanks..for suggest....if you have no problem..can u give me your email id..i sent the sample code on which i have some problem....bcoz in my code there are pagetab sliding strip in custimized form. My email is chandreshrana140@gmail.com